# Delaunay triangulation and distance calculation with CGAL

Tags: c++, geometry, binary-tree, computational-geometry, cgal

I am trying to create a binary tree construction algorithm based on only the edges constructed by the Delaunay triangulation of all the points in 2D space.

I've started reading the [documentation](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Triangulation_2/index.html) on 2D triangulations but it seems a bit overwhelming to me as a newbie and also I just read [here](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Triangulation_2/index.html#Triangulation_2ARepresentationBasedonFaces) that the triangulation is represented as only the faces of the triangles and the vertices they consist of.
For my algorithm to work, I need to know the shortest distance between 2 vertices that are connected by an edge in a Delaunay triangulation. Additionally I need to be able to delete 2 vertices and 1 to the triangulation when 2 need to be joined together into a parent node in the tree without needing to recalculate the whole triangulation.

Is this something that I can do with CGAL? Or will I have to recalculate all the distances between the vertices in all the triangles?

Comment: This might be clearer if you explain what it is you are trying to do.

Comment: Are you trying to construct a [euclidean minimal spanning tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_minimum_spanning_tree) ?

Comment: @jwezorek ok ill try:
Say you have N points in a 2D plane, I want to construct a binary tree where the leaves are going to be those points. First, i want to create a Delaunay triangulation of all the points, and then i merge the 2 points that are connected in that triangulation with the shortest distance. Those 2 points are removed from the triangulation and the parent node is inserted in the triangulation as a point (probably in the middle of the 2 child points). And then repeat until a single point is left and the tree is completed.

Comment: @ChrisD no no, I'm trying to create a binary tree

Comment: CGAL's implementation of 2D delaunay triangulations does support inserting and deleting vertices but there is going to be no efficient way to find the two vertices with the shortest edge between them just from the triangulation. I mean, you can do it by linear search over the edges; to do better than that you'd need to maintain your own data structure, updating it as you delete and insert vertices.

Comment: @jwezorek yeah i guess ill have to iterate through all the edges myself and calculate distances, i was just a bit worried because at first the documentation said that it only saves "faces and vertices" in the representation. Do you know of any other library that can do a delaunay triangulation that also supports insertion/removal with which i can do this easier?

Comment: OpenCV has delaunay routines but it's similar to CGAL. I mean, nothing is going to have some special way of returning the shortest edge in sublinear time.

Comment: @jwezorek i thought of maybe passing it a custom functor for the distance calculations it does internally that also saves the result in a data structure. Do you think that would add too much overhead?

Comment: If you have a face `(i, j, k)` the edges are just `(i, j)`, `(j, k)`, and `(k, i)`. What were you worried about?

Comment: @ChrisD i was thinking that if i had to do that for every face, then i would do double computations since each edge is a part of 2 faces. But from what i now understand CGAL seems to have an edge iterator which should be good for my usecase